# Help with proving that $A^p \equiv A$ mod $p$ does not mean that $A$ is diagonalizable

Tags: modular-arithmetic, diagonalization

I'm working on a matrix extension of Fermat's Little Theorem, but I'm stuck on trying to show that if $A^p \equiv A$ mod $p$, then $A$ does not have to be diagonalizable.

Any help would be appreciated!

**Edit::** I would like to either find a reason why $A$ does not have to be diagonalizable, or somehow be able to categorize the matrices that are / are not diagonalizable in a way that would suggest a pattern. An example would be that if $A^p \equiv A$ mod $p$, then $A$ is diagonalizable when xxx or not diagonalizable when xxx.

Comment: Try looking at the matrix ((1,1),(0,1)).

Comment: @Nate tried it, not a counterexample

Comment: Actually in mod p, any matrix in the form $\begin{bmatrix} p & p \\ 0 & p \end{bmatrix}$ is a counterexample.

Comment: That's the zero matrix, which is diagonalizable @Peter.

Comment: It may be significant that $\mathbb{F}_p$ is not algebraically closed

Comment: So my issue with figuring out if $A$ is diagonalizable or not has to do with the transition matrix $X$, which is the matrix of eigenvectors of $A$. If $X$ is singular, then $A$ is not diagonalizable. What are some properties or characteristics that would make the matrix of eigenvectors singular??

Comment: I think this might happen if $A$ satisfies a polynomial that is irreducible over $\mathbb{F}_p$, but has no repeated roots in $\mathbb{C}$.

Answer (score 3):

What people generally think of as the generalization of Fermat's Little Theorem is as follows:

Let $p$ be prime and $A\in GL_n(\mathbb{Z})$. Then $tr(A^p)=tr(A)$ mod $p$, where $tr(A)$ denotes the trace of the matrix $A$. In fact, this holds even more generally: $tr(A^{p^k})=tr(A^{p^{k-1}})$ mod $p^k$ where the first statement is the case for $k=1$

The first statement was proven by V.I. Arnold (who also conjectured the second). The second was proven by [Alexander Zarelua in 2008](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1134/S008154380804007X).

Answer (score 1):

You haven't been clear about your base field. Let $k=\Bbb R$. Consider $p=2$. Then $\begin{pmatrix}1&2\\0&1\end{pmatrix}$ is congruent to its square modulo two. However, it is not diagonalizable over $\Bbb R$, say, since it is a Jordan block.

Comment: You have $A^3 = \pmatrix{1&6\\0&1} \equiv \pmatrix{1&0\\0&1}$, so you're not quite there.

Comment: Oh, SIGH. @Omnomnomnom